# repeat JS file upload with setinterval

Tags: javascript, html

I got a JS code snippet that shows XLSX file contents on HTML, Using a browse button to select the file, and upload to show the XLSX contents, I'm trying to automate it to keep on refreshing the page each 30 seconds to pull the data from Excel again.

Tried with setinterval, but didn't work. ( as it's not re-uploading the file again, simply nothing happens, I've to open the page and re-select the file and press upload again).

here is the code so far

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" onclick="Upload()" />
    <hr />
    <div id="dvExcel">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/jszip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function Upload() {
            //Reference the FileUpload element.
            var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
             var newtime = 3000
            //Validate whether File is valid Excel file.
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xls|.xlsx)$/;
            if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    //For Browsers other than IE.
                    if (reader.readAsBinaryString) {
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            ProcessExcel(e.target.result);
                        };
                        reader.readAsBinaryString(fileUpload.files[0]);
                    } else {
                        //For IE Browser.
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            var data = "";
                            var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                            for (var i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
                                data += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                            }
                            ProcessExcel(data);
                        };
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileUpload.files[0]);
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Please upload a valid Excel file.");
            }
        };

    function ProcessExcel(data) {
            //Read the Excel File data.
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                type: 'binary'
            });

            //Fetch the name of First Sheet.
            var firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0];

            //Read all rows from First Sheet into an JSON array.
            var excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);

            //Create a HTML Table element.
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            table.border = "1";

            //Add the header row.
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);

            //Add the header cells.
            var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "Name";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);

            headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "ChatStatus";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);

            headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "EmailStatus";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);


            headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "Duration";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);            


            //Add the data rows from Excel file.
            for (var i = 0; i < excelRows.length; i++) {
                //Add the data row.
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);

                //Add the data cells.
                var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Name;

                cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].ChatStatus;

                cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].EmailStatus;


                cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Duration;
            }

            var dvExcel = document.getElementById("dvExcel");
            dvExcel.innerHTML = "";
            dvExcel.appendChild(table);
        };
        var myVar = setInterval(ProcessExcel(), 3000);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it "didn't work"?

Comment: you need to call `reader.readAsArrayBuffer` each time you want a fresh copy of the file. if you actually refresh the page, you will lose the file selection, and thus have to click it each time. but populated files will update themselves in the input if the file changes, all you need to do is re-read them to get the latest. You may want to check the file date to avoid some work and/or screen flashiness if nothing has changed since last time. You can use my watchfile lib to make it somewhat easier: https://github.com/rndme/watchfile

Comment: Thanks Dan!, I will check that out, But i'm fine with the update each x Interval, even if the source XLXS didn't change.